# Clipboard does not paste correct hyperlink on Outlook 2007

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, clipboard, hyperlink

Last week this problem is not showing however today when i paste a copied a hyperlinked text on outlook, it won't appear correctly.

i changed every settings to default and to no avail.
i don't have administrative rights because the laptop is company owned.

I also tried the following:

1. Click an email
2. Reply to All
3. Copy hyperlinked text = "[1234]" with hyperlinked to a URL
4. Paste on top of the email
5. "[1234]" text was pasted but without the hyperlink

it will save me a ton of time because i copy a lot of that kind of text.

Comment: Did you try pressing enter after pasting the hyperlink? I noticed pasted hyperlinks do not become click-able links until you press enter.

Comment: yeah, actually the text is hyperlinked. example "[12345]" is linked to a URL but i don't paste the whole URL.

Comment: OK. The way #5 reads it sounds like it is not.

Comment: sorry :) i'll clear the description. thx